# Training stop after step 1 in Tensorflow model api ssd mobilenet in google colab

Tags: tensorflow

Recently i am trying to train ssd mobilenet object detection model of tensorflow model api on my custom data set in google colab, after step 1 the training session stopped without showing or throwing any exception or message.I can not figure out the issue.Can anyone please give any explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be the issue due to limited RAM. You can try:-

- See the size of Training Data sample(resize to smaller dimension)

In configuring file:-

- Reduce your batch size
- Disable Data augmentation
- Set the following parameters low.

For example:-

```
  train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  ...
  batch_queue_capacity: 50
  num_batch_queue_threads: 8
  prefetch_queue_capacity: 10
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yograj for your answer. I have set batch size to 1. How can i disable data augmentation?

Comment: My train.record file size is 328 MB and test.record size is 58 MB

Comment: my training set contains high resolution images. size of each image is 3.5-4 MB and resolution is  4128*3096.

Comment: You can find data_augmentation_options  in the config file. By commenting out that part you can disable it.

Comment: I have commented out data_augmentation_option,  but still training is stopping after global step 1

Comment: me too here, whatever configs, it stops at step 1 :(

Comment: can you check with a smaller image dimension about (50,50,3)? If it works then try to increase gradually and see.

Answer (score 1):

Training stops after 1 step means you have only 1 batch to process.

```
num_batches = num_epochs * (num_samples / batch_size)
```

Even setting `steps` to a very big value, it will stop after step 1 if `num_batches` above is just 1.